Git-lfs screwed up Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
I am really stuck with git lfs. This is the first time I was trying to use it. I was on a feature branch. I ran [1]:
git lfs install
git lfs track *.bin
git add .gitattributes

and then kept working on this feature branch. I made many commits and when it was time to push to main I did an interactive rebase to squash the many commits I had done on local feature branch (this was my mistake it seems):
git rebase -i HEAD~21

This is when all hell broke loose. I got this error:
Downloading xxx/src/main/resources/xxx.xxx (91 MB)
Error downloading object: xxx/src/main/resources/xxx.xxx (ca46f1a): Smudge error: Error downloading xxx/src/main/resources/xxx.xxx (ca46f1a88a9c6e61b918af1ab38be3e7903b986616551f0a6f10a7ecc5730cd4): [ca46f1a88a9c6e61b918af1ab38be3e7903b986616551f0a6f10a7ecc5730cd4] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server

It is true, the object does not exist on the server. I completed my rebase somehow but now I cannot push anything to the remote repository. It keeps complaining:
remote: error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 1 unknown Git LFS object:
remote:     ca46f1a88a9c6e61b918af1ab38be3e7903b986616551f0a6f10a7ecc5730cd4

How do I fix this please?

To clarify, you haven't pushed anything yet? And now you have just 1 commit with 1 version of the large file you wish to push?

No. I have pushed code but not the lfs file. My understanding is that when it was squashing the commits in my feature branch, it tried to run git lfs checkout to restore the file (?) and that's when it complained of being unable to download since it was not pushed to the remote in the first place. seems like a bug in the tool but how do I get around it now?
